# OpenSource Mano (OSM) & OpenStack : "The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)"

Tags: networking, openstack, virtualization

Currently working on Newtorks Virtualization, I am trying to configure OpenStack and Open Source MANO to make them work together. I am following the OSM tutorial (https://osm.etsi.org/wikipub/index.php/OSM_Release_TWO). I have a problem at the step « Instantiating a NS ». After clicking on Launch, I’ve got the following message:

```
VIM Exception vimconnUnexpectedResponse Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication.
(HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-83c01de4-4942-414c-8431-73ee089dd1b6). 
(False, " Rollback fails to delete: ['network TASK.1498137381.233714 from VIM openstack-site2']")
```

I don't understand where it is coming from. When I am trying to connect in a navigator to the address I put when creating the datacenter (10.0.3.44:8447/v2.1), I get the same HTTP 401 error. This address is the one I found in the "API Access » section of the OpenStack UI for the compute service. I used it to create the datacenter in openmano:

```
openmano datacenter-create openstack-site http://10.0.3.44:8447/v2.1 --type openstack --description "OpenStack site"
openmano datacenter-attach openstack-site --user=admin --password=mypwd --vim-tenant-name=admin
```

Does anyone know what could be my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the adress I was using. If you encounter the same problem, try to use the adress :

```
http://<openstack machine IP>/identity/v2.0
```

By example, in my case, I used the commands:

```
openmano datacenter-create openstack-site http://10.0.3.44/identity/v2.0 --type openstack --description "OpenStack site"
openmano datacenter-attach openstack-site --user=admin --password=mypwd --vim-tenant-name=admin
```